# Does solidity language optimizes code or is it dependent on Compiler for gas/machine cycles?

Tags: solidity, compilation

Take the following case

```
uint256 x = z * 100/1000;//1st statement

uint256 y = z * 1/10;// 2nd statement
```

Now in terms of Gas and Machinecyles as well as will solidity spend more computational resources on the first statement or are both statements treated equally in terms of computation. Also does the compiler used affect the computational reource used in calculating those statements?

Answer (score 1):

The Solidity compiler has an extensive optimizer that is constantly being improved. See the [Optimizer](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/internals/optimizer.html) section in the docs if you want more details.

> Now in terms of Gas and Machinecyles as well as will solidity spend more computational resources on the first statement or are both statements treated equally in terms of computation.

They are exactly equivalent. The Solidity compiler has a constant optimizer that will replace both `100/1000` and `1/10` by the computed result in generated bytecode.

> Also does the compiler used affect the computational reource used in calculating those statements?

If you mean a completely different compiler like [solang](https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/solang) then it of course depends. Different compilers may offer different optimizations. I think that having a constant optimizer is a pretty safe bet though.

If you meant an older version of solc, then newer versions will of course have better optimizations. The constant optimizer, however, is fundamental enough that you can expect this to work even in pretty old versions.

As far as future improvements go, there's a new [Yul-based optimizer](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/internals/optimizer.html#yul-based-optimizer-module) in the works. It's still considered experimental but you can already try it by enabling the `--experimental-via-ir` option. Since it operates on an intermediate language (Yul) it can provide much more advanced optimizations.